# How to get a model to use the object to which it belongs in a private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each User has_many Personas. A User is allowed up to three Personas, and before each Personas is created they are assigned a persona_id of 1, 2 or 3 depending on how many Personas the User already has. The Persona's persona_id is set in a before_validation callback using the set_persona_id private method. My questions is: how do you pass the User to which the Persona belongs to the set_persona_id method? The code below fails. Unit tests reveal that self.user is nil. I tried passing self as an argument to set_persona_id (as in `set_persona_id(self)` but that also failed, producing a nil user.

Persona.rb:

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  before_validation do
    set_persona_id
  end

  before_save do
    self.callsign.downcase!
  end

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length:   { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX = /\A[a-z\d\-.\_]+\z/i
  validates :callsign, presence:   true,
                       length:     { maximum: 20 },
                       format:     { with: VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX },
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :persona_id, presence: true

  def to_param
    callsign
  end

  private

    def set_persona_id
      if ( self.user.personas.count == 0 )
        self.persona_id = 1
        return
      end
      if ( self.user.personas.count == 1 )
        if self.user.personas.first.persona_id == 1
          self.persona_id = 2
          return
        else
          self.persona_id = 1
          return
        end
      end
      if ( self.user.personas.count == 2 )
        if self.user.personas.first.persona_id == 1
          if self.user.personas.second.persona_id == 2
            self.persona_id = 3
            return
          else
            self.persona_id = 2
            return
          end
        end
        if self.user.personas.first.persona_id == 2
          if self.user.personas.second.persona_id == 1
            self.persona_id = 3
            return
          else
            self.persona_id = 1
            return
          end
        end
        if self.user.personas.first.persona_id == 3
          if self.user.personas.second.persona_id == 1
            self.persona_id = 2
            return
          else
            self.persona_id = 1
            return
          end
        end
      end
    end # set_persona_id

end # Persona
```

persona_test.rb:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", callsign: "example",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  @user.save
  @persona = @user.personas.build(name: "Bazman", callsign: "Baz")
  @persona.persona_id = 1
end
```

EDIT:

Personas are created by the user filling in some forms and clicking on a 'Create a new persona' button:

views/personas/new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create persona') %>
<h1>Create a new persona</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@persona) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :callsign %>
      <%= f.text_field :callsign %>

      <%= f.submit "Create a new persona", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the Personas controller:

```
def create
  @persona = current_user.personas.build(persona_params)
  if @persona.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome, " + @persona.name
    redirect_to @persona
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Share an example of how you are creating the object. And also try "user" instead of "self.user".

Comment: So, I'm confused about the reason for the `persona_id` column in the first place. What are its purposes; are you merely using it to ensure that the user never has more than 3 `Persona` relationships? If that is the case, I think we can definitely find an easier way to handle this, as I think you're doing a lot of work for something that can likely be done much simpler.

Comment: Using just "user" instead of "self.user" produces the same error: user is nil.

Comment: I have the `persona_id` column for more than just ensuring there are no more than three. I need to differentiate between the three personas. For example, personas can be deleted by the user if he chooses.

Comment: See the EDIT for how personas are created.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the line `@persona.save` in the test:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", callsign: "example",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")#, activated: true)
  @user.save
  @persona = @user.personas.build(name: "Bazman", callsign: "Baz")
  @persona.save
  @persona.persona_id = 1
end
```

It seems that if `foo belongs_to bar` then `foo.bar` is nil unless foo has been saved to the database.